# MySQL Join different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to join the following tables with the following code, but I can't join the last columns.

```
Table:magazine
id_mag  **mag_name**  id_freq

Table:frequency
id_freq  **freq_name**

Table:copy
id_mag  **id_copy** **copy_date** copy_price copy_page_number

Table:article
id_art **art_name** **art_page_number**

Table:copy_art
id_mag **id_copy** id_art article_page_num
```

I want to show a table with the following columns. The columns in the tables magazine, frequency, copy, article & copy_art that have ** ** are the ones I am interested in to be showed:

```
mag_name  freq_name  id_copy  copy_date  art_name  art_page_number
```

I got the following table with this code:

```
  SELECT * FROM magazine
  JOIN frequency ON magazine.id_freq = frequency.id_freq
  JOIN copy_art ON revista.id_mag=copy_art.id_mag
  JOIN article ON copy_art.id_art=article.id_art
  JOIN copy ON copy_art.id_copy=copy.id_copy;
```

**Here is the translation for the name of each column that appears in the image:**

```
id_rev = id_mag
nom_rev = mag_name
id_frec = id_freq
nom_frec = freq_name
id_rev = id_mag
id_ejem = id_copy
id_art = id_art
num_pag = article_page_num
nom_art = art_name
num_pag_art = art_page_number
fecha_ejem = copy_date
precio = copy_price
```

[image: Table 1]

**My doubt is the following:**

- What should I do in order to have the table with?

  mag_name freq_name id_copy copy_date art_name article_page_num

Thanks a lot for your kindly support!

Comment: What's the error message? Don't you need some `GROUP BY` statements? 
Could you translate table names to English? Should be that much easier to wrap one's head around it.

Comment: Done! I just changed all the column names and tables to English! :D

Comment: It isn't very fair to @folkol to change the table names after he has provided an answer using the original names.  If you do that, you should edit the answer too, making the names in the answer consistent with the revised names in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want a few columns in the output, then you have to list which columns you do want.  The key structure of the data is unclear (meaning it isn't clear which columns are the primary keys of each table); you have the `id_mag` and `id_copy` columns both appearing in `copy` and `copy_art` and it isn't entirely clear whether they're a composite key or `id_copy` is sufficient.  Given that we don't have that information, we'll have to take your SELECT statement and its joins as gospel, but I'm not convinced that's correct.

You wrote:

```
SELECT *
  FROM magazine
  JOIN frequency ON magazine.id_freq = frequency.id_freq
  JOIN copy_art ON revista.id_mag=copy_art.id_mag
  JOIN article ON copy_art.id_art=article.id_art
  JOIN copy ON copy_art.id_copy=copy.id_copy;
```

This collects all the columns from all the tables mentioned, which is wasteful.  So, you need to specify which columns you do want:

```
SELECT m.mag_name, f.freq_name, c.id_copy, c.copy_date, a.art_name, a.art_page_number
  FROM magazine  AS m
  JOIN frequency AS f ON m.id_freq = f.id_freq
  JOIN copy_art  AS y ON m.id_mag  = y.id_mag
  JOIN article   AS a ON y.id_art  = a.id_art
  JOIN copy      AS c ON y.id_copy = c.id_copy;
```

I'm not entirely sure that you need the `copy_art` table in the query, but I'm assuming you know your data better than I do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that one of the first tables has got a foreign key for the articulo table to join that as well.

If you add that (For example in the revista table), you can make a JOIN over all tables with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM revista
  JOIN frecuencia ON revista.id_frec = frecuencia.id_frec
  JOIN ejemplar ON revista.id_rev = ejemplar.id_rev
  JOIN articulo ON revista.id_art = articulo.id_art;
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2e30/1) for an example (I query * here, you can change that to just the columns that you need).

Comment: Thanks! I just miss to show the revista.id_rev=ejem_art.id_rev columns

Comment: No problems. Next time, please take some time to translate your code to English! :)

Comment: I just noticed you added id_art to revista, it does not have that column therefore I had to modify the code folkol ...

Comment: Yes, as I said in the answer. To join them all, you will have to add something to join them on.

Comment: I think I should use the table copy_art to do so, right?

Comment: You can store it wherever you want :) I was not sure what the tables and columns meant when I added the answer. Just change it however you want.

Comment: Could you help me with the updates folkol? :) I just realized I just miss a few details.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. The columns should be returned in the order that you answer for them, so I have no idea what the last picture comes from. Are you use that one is generated by the query above it? It doesn't even seem to be the same columns as in the query.

Comment: I will update my post with my final result. I think I did not write the post as clear as I could, sorry!

Comment: I'm just heading for bed though. But keep trying, and take a step back and argue with yourself why it should work. And then try to find out why it doesn't.

Good luck!